# Carry on information about previous computations

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming, so some problems seems harder to solve using functional approach.

Let's say I have a list of numbers, like 1 to 10.000, and I want to get the items of the list which sums up to at most a number n (let's say 100). So, it would get the numbers until their sum is greater than 100.

In imperative programming, it's trivial to solve this problem, because I can keep a variable in each interaction, and stop once the objective is met.

But how can I do the same in functional programming? Since the sum function operates on completed lists, and I still don't have the completed list, how can I 'carry on' the computation?

If sum was lazily computed, I could write something like that:

```
           (1 to 10000).sum.takeWhile(_ < 100)
```

P.S.:Even though any answer will be appreciated, I'd like one that doesn't compute the sum each time, since obviously the imperative version will be much more optimal regarding speed.

Edit:

I know that I can "convert" the imperative loop approach to a functional recursive function. I'm more interested in finding if one of the existing library functions can provide a way for me not to write one each time I need something.

Comment: Probably easiest to use a variable accumulator. `{ var sum = 0; (1 to 10000) takeWhile { i => sum += i; sum < 100 } }`. Nothing wrong with having a `var` here; it can't escape because the expression has `{}` around it.

Comment: Why do you think that writing a function "each time you need something" is less natural than writing an imperative loop each time you need something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html).

```
scala> val ss = Stream.from(1).take(10000)
ss: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> ss.scanLeft(0)(_ + _)
res60: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(0, ?)

scala> res60.takeWhile(_ < 100).last
res61: Int = 91
```

**EDIT:**

Obtaining components is not very tricky either. This is how you can do it:

```
scala> ss.scanLeft((0, Vector.empty[Int])) { case ((sum, compo), cur) => (sum + cur, compo :+ cur) }
res62: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int])] = Stream((0,Vector()), ?)

scala> res62.takeWhile(_._1 < 100).last
res63: (Int, scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]) = (91,Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13))
```

The second part of the tuple is your desired result.

As should be obvious, in this case, building a vector is wasteful. Instead we can only store the last number from the stream that contributed to sum.

```
scala> ss.scanLeft(0)(_ + _).zipWithIndex
res64: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, Int)] = Stream((0,0), ?)

scala> res64.takeWhile(_._1 < 100).last._2
res65: Int = 13
```

Comment: I thought the OP asked about the items and not the sum. This seems to be a bit more tricky.

Comment: Ziggystar, you are right. I want to get the items of the list. This scanLeft does solve some problems, but it doesn't return the items which sum till 100.

Comment: Just to see if I got it: you use scanLeft to create the sum and, at the same time, collect the components (through a tuple). Then you take from the Stream till the sum reaches its maximum. Very clever! And, though wasteful, I really need to create the vector because in some cases the numbers are not in sequence. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do this is with recursion. On each call, add the next number. Your base case is when the sum is greater than 100, at which point you return all the way up the stack. You'll need a helper function to do the actual recursion, but that's no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't hard using "functional" methods either.
Using recursion, rather than maintaining your state in a local variable that you mutate, you keep it in parameters and return values.

So, to return the longest initial part of a list whose sum is at most `N`:

1. If the list is empty, you're done; return the empty list.
2. If the head of the list is greater than `N`, you're done; return the empty list.
3. Otherwise, let `H` be the head of the list.
   All we need now is the initial part of the *tail* of the list whose sum is at most `N - H`, then we can "cons" `H` onto that list, and we're done.
   We can compute this recursively using the same procedure as we have used this far, so it's an easy step.

A simple pseudocode solution:

```
sum_to (n, ls) = if isEmpty ls or n < (head ls)
                 then Nil
                 else (head ls) :: sum_to (n - head ls, tail ls)

sum_to(100, some_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

All sequence operations which require only one pass through the sequence can be implemented using folds our reduce like it is sometimes called.
I find myself using folds very often since I became used to functional programming

so here odd one possible approach
Use an empty collection as initial value and fold according to this strategy
Given the processed collection and the new value check if their sum is low enough and if then spend the value to the collection else do nothing

that solution is not very efficient but I want to emphasize the following
map fold filter zip etc are the way to get accustomed to functional programming try to use them as much as possible instead of loping constructs or recursive functions your code will be more declarative and functional